# How to add some external links to ROBOT Framework Test Statistics in log.html and output.xml?

Tags: python, robotframework

How can I customize my robot framework log.html and  output so that I can add some external links to my output files like log.html and output.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use metadata in your test suites. Those metadata can contains external links. This is explained in the "[Free test suite metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-test-suite-metadata)" section of the User Guide.

Here is how it looks if you use TXT format for your tests:

```
*** Settings ***
Metadata   Here is a link    http://www.external.com/pages.html
```

And that will be included in your output.xml and report.html

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to add links to a robot framework log. They are all documented in the [Robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

#### Adding links to tags

You can add links to tags with the --tagstatlink option. These links will show up in the "statistics by tag" section of the log. Here are the examples from the robot framework user's guide:

```
--tagstatlink mytag:http://www.google.com:Google
--tagstatlink jython-bug-*:http://bugs.jython.org/issue_%1:Jython-bugs
--tagstatlink owner-*:mailto:%1@domain.com?subject=Acceptance_Tests:Send_Mail
```

This is documented in the section titled [Creating links from tag names](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-links-from-tag-names) in the robot framework users guide.

#### Adding links via log statements

You can add any HTML you want by using the special log level `HTML`. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | log | For more information see <a href='...'>foo</a> | HTML
```

This is documented in the section titled [Logging information](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information) in the robot framework users guide.

#### Adding links via free test suite metadata

You can add links in the free test suite metadata. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Metadata  | More Info 
| ... | For more informationabout *Robot Framework* see http://robotframework.org
```

This is documented in the section titled [Free test suite metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-test-suite-metadata) in the robot framework users guide.

You can also call the [Set Suite Metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Metadata) keyword from anywhere in a test case or keyword.

### Adding links in documentation

You can add links in test suite, test case, and keyword documentation. This is the example from the users guide:

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | [Documentation]
| | ... | See [http://www.robotframework.org]|robot framework website]
```

This is documented in the section titled [Custom links and images](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#custom-links-and-images) in the robot framework users guide.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add **top-level** metadata.
And that metadata would be an HTML link.

Create a suit setup for the master suite (create a file called __init__.robot in 
the parent test folder)

And in it:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     The main init phase for all robot framework tests.
Suite Setup  Setup

*** Keywords ***

Setup
    Set Suite Metadata  Link to my cool external site  http://www.external.com  top=True
```